# Confused about UnsafeMutablePtr capacity in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers

I'd like to understand why certain pointer APIs need a capacity as an argument. Like `UnsafeMutablePtr.deallocate`, or `UnsafeMutableRawPointer.bindMemory()`. This is in direct contrast to C memory management, where `free()` and pointer casting does not need size.

I assume these Swift APIs are using `malloc()` and `free()` under the hood. So, why do I need a capacity here? There are some structs - like [MIDIPacketList](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/midipacketlist) -whose size is ill-defined (because it's "open-ended", as the documentation puts it, the size can be determined by examining the contents), I can put capacity=1 in a case like this but that would be technically incorrect. Is it a mistake, or it doesn't matter? I don't see why capacity would be needed at all for casting (and freeing, for that matter).

Also, this sentence "After rebinding the memory referenced by uint8Pointer to UInt64, accessing that pointer’s referenced memory as a UInt8 instance is undefined." in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablepointer) is also hard to grasp, as in C you when you are casting, your original pointer remains valid. Is there some essential difference between C style casting and 'rebinding' ?

Comment: I have only learned a little Swift, but I assume if it points to multiple contiguous objects it would have to know how many to call out the destructors?

Comment: No, that is what `.deinitialize` does, but the doc explicitly states that `.deallocate` expects not initialized/already uninitialized memory (or memory containing trivial types).

Comment: "So, why do I need a capacity here?" Because this tells how _much_ memory to set aside, and also allows access via subscripting with some degree of safety. " Is there some essential difference between C style casting and 'rebinding' ?" No, but a method like `withMemoryRebound` also defines a _scope_ in which that rebinding is valid and the memory won't vanish, again providing a degree of safety.

Comment: There were some discussions about that on swift-users. For example https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20161031/003863.html: *"Nothing observable happens at the call to ptrT = bindMemory(to: T.self, …)."* and *"This API will make it easier to develop static diagnostics that catch undefined behavior and much easier to write a runtime sanitizer. Neither of those things exist yet. "* – So as I understand it (and I may be wrong), `bindMemory` and `withMemoryRebound` is only about semantics and currently does *nothing* at runtime, it just returns the pointer.